# how can i substr in oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, procedure

this is my procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE testsub(factTName IN VARCHAR2)
IS
  v_in_char VARCHAR2(100):='id,name,age,cjrq';
  v_result VARCHAR2(200) :='';
begin
  -- split v_in_char,expect cjrq
  -- i want result like t.uuid=uuid and t.uuname=uuname and t.uuage=uuage

  SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_result);
end;
```

Comment: would you format your question - it helps to read it :)

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to split the constant string defined in your procedure, or do you want to split the input to the procedure?

Comment: it is not clear for me as well. Anyway combination of two functions : **substr** and **instr** should allow you to substr you string.

Comment: Do a little searching before posting, there are a million questions and answers on parsing delimited strings.

Comment: i have resolved this problem.thank u guys.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
select substr(v_in_char,instr(v_in_char,',',1,3)+1) into v_result 
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace PROCEDURE testsub(factTName IN VARCHAR2)
IS
  v_primy_keys VARCHAR2(200) :='';
  cursor primy_key is
    select field_en_name from BASE_FIELD_INFO where base_rpt_id=lower(factTName) and primy_key='true';
  primy_key_row  primy_key%ROWTYPE;
begin
  for primy_key_row in primy_key loop
    IF primy_key_row.field_en_name='CJRQ' THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
    ELSE
      v_primy_keys:=v_primy_keys||'t.'||primy_key_row.field_en_name||'='||primy_key_row.field_en_name||' ';
    END IF;
    v_primy_keys:=v_primy_keys||' and ';
  end loop;
  v_primy_keys:=substr(v_primy_keys,1,length(v_primy_keys)-4);
  dbms_output.put_line(v_primy_keys);
end;
```